# How to display php error message in html page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to display error messgae in html page during login from validation. 
Kindly check my code:

```
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">            
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 
 **<br><br>
  <span id="modal_errors_1" class="bg-danger"></span>**

</form>


 <?php

$errors = array();

$required = array(

'email'     => 'Email',
'password'  => 'Password',

);


 // check if all required fileds are fill out
 foreach ($required as $field => $display) {
 if (empty($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '') {
 $errors[] = $display.' is required.';
 }
 }

 **// Assume both fields are empty so it must give the error message**
 if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
 $errors[] = 'You must provide email and password.';
 }

 // VAlidate Email
 if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 $errors[] = 'Invalid email format';
 }


 // Display Errrors Code
 function display_errors1($errors1){
 $display = '#modal_errors_1';
 foreach ($errors1 as $error) {
 $display .= '#modal_errors_1'.$error.'</span></li>';
 }
 $display .= '#modal_errors_1';
 return $display;
 }
 ?>
```

Now I want to display $errors[] like in image below after the Login submit button in red background with white text.

[image]

Comment: `echo display_errors1($errors);` is a start. But what is `#modal_errors_1` supposed to be/to do?

Comment: @ Jeff, Hi Jeff How are you doing? Thanks for the reply. #modal_errors_1 is a div id <div id="modal_errors_1"></div> You got it right. I don't have any idea how to achieve desired result like in image.

Comment: @jeff, I want to do something like echo '<div id="modal_errors_1">' .$errors[]. '</div>' ;

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML form and PHP $_POST processing routine are in the same script just process before the form:

```
$errors = [];
$required = [
    'email'     => 'Email',
    'password'  => 'Password',
];

// check if all required fileds are fill out
foreach ($required as $field => $display) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '') {
        $errors[] = $display.' is required.';
    }
}

$required_msg = '';
if(count($errors)) {
    $required_msg = '<span id="modal_errors_1" class="bg-danger">'
        . implode('<br/>', $errors)
        . '</span>';
}

?>
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">            
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 
**<br><br>
<?= $required_msg ?>**

</form>
```

Or if it's in another script, just redirect-back to your login form with an argument, for example : login.php?errlogin, then:

```
$required_msg = '';
if(isset($_GET['errlogin'])) {
    $required_msg = '<span id="modal_errors_1" class="bg-danger">
        Login is required
        </span>';
}

?>
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">            
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login"> 
**<br><br>
<?= $required_msg ?>**

</form>
```

**Edit:** And use HTML required arguments too in your form fields :

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

And if your username is meant to be an email, use the `type="email"` field.

Comment: Side note: "required" can be bypassed. Best to validate on the serverside. [See this Q&A](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/169771/34623).

Comment: Absolutely, I said "use too", not instead. Ultimate verifications must always be done server side.